# Easy way to exclude django _state attribute from jsonpickle.encode

Tags: python, django, jsonpickle

I have a python class which is not a Django model object:

```
class APIBase:
    data = object

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def toJSON(self):
        return jsonpickle.encode(self, unpicklable=False)
```

However the `data` attribute of this class can contain a Django model, and when this is encoded by jsonpickle, the JSON string contains a private [_state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11562044/44540) attribute from Django, which I don't want encoded.

Is there an easy way to exclude this without resorting to writing my own encoder? I can rely on the fact that only the `data` attribute can contain the Django model.

I'm still learning python and django, but from my understanding the convention is any attribute starting with an underscore is considered private, so I was surprised to see this being encoded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
def toJSON(self):
    clone = copy.deepcopy(self)
    if getattr(clone.data, '_state', False):
        del clone.data._state
    return jsonpickle.encode(clone, unpicklable=False)
```