# Django execute custom code after user signup

Tags: django, django-models

I have a `users` app in a Django project (version `2.1` and python `3.6`). After an user signup (both front end and when added in the admin dashboard ideally), I'd like to insert data in one other table. I know how to insert data, but I didn't find out how to do it right after a successfull signup.

Ideal answer would just show me how to do something like `print('hello')` right after an user created his account.

```
# users/admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ['email', 'username',]

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

---

```
# users/forms.py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email')

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email')
```

---

```
# users/models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # add additional fields in here
    credit = models.IntegerField(default=200) # editable=False
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

---

```
# users/urls.py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.SignUp.as_view(), name='signup'),
]
```

---

```
# users/views.py
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic

from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm

class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a post-save signal

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def say_hello(sender, instance, **kwargs):
     if instate._state.adding:
        print('hello')
```

Signal is better than a method on the view because the User may be created some way other than through the view e.g , via the shell, a management command, a migration, a different view, etc.

Note the [_state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11562044/904887) is not "private" so don't feel bad about using it, it's just named that way to avoid clashing with field names.

Check _state instead of more common checking instance.pk because instance.pk is always present when primary key is a natural key rather than AutoField

Comment: This seems like the solution for me but sadly it doesn't seems to works, I put this code in users/models.py and changed `sender=User` to `sender=CustomUser`. (Also you have a typo on `instate._state.adding:`, guess you meant `instance`  :)

Comment: Well got it partially working : the `instance._state` doesn't seems to be `True` since the `hello` is not printed but calling `print` before it works. Would like to figure out why before accepting this answer

Comment: Well, found out I can do this : `say_hello(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):` and then use `created` in place of `instate._state.adding`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach would be overriding `save` method of `CustomUser` model. For example:

```
class CustomUser(AbstructUser):

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         user = super(CustomUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
         print("Hello World")
         return user
```

Check here in Django documentation for more details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods.

Comment: The problem with using that is that it would also be called when updating an user. But for now it sounds like a fine solution. However after searching the docs I've learnt a bit more about `
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)` which seems more usefull for this specific use case